# Move and rotate animation at same using CSS3 and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, box2dweb

I am having some fun with box2dweb. The following code is located in my step method which gets called about 30/sec, the code works but a am curios if there is a way of improving it?

```
var img = body.GetUserData();
var pos = body.GetPosition();
var newPos = {x: meterToPixelCenter(pos.x,scale,img.width) , y:meterToPixelCenter(pos.y,scale,img.height)};

img.style.left = newPos.x + 'px';
img.style.top = newPos.y + 'px';

var style = 'rotate(' + (body.GetAngle() * 57.2957795) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
img.style.WebkitTransform = style;
img.style.MozTransform = style;
img.style.OTransform = style;
img.style.msTransform = style;
img.style.transform = style;
```

I would like to use CSS3 translate for moving the object:

```
var stylePos = 'translate(' + newPos.x + 'px' + ',' + newPos.y + 'px' + ')';
img.style.WebkitTransform = stylePos;
img.style.MozTransform = stylePos;
img.style.OTransform = stylePos;
img.style.msTransform = stylePos;
img.style.transform = stylePos;

var style = 'rotate(' + (body.GetAngle() * 57.2957795) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
img.style.WebkitTransform = style;
img.style.MozTransform = style;
img.style.OTransform = style;
img.style.msTransform = style;
img.style.transform = style;
```

How am I able to do both (rotate and translate)? Would this increase performance?

Comment: Can I ask why are you using javascript to add so much styling and effects? You can do this in CSS. If you need to being and end the effects using javascript, you can still set them up with CSS and just add or remove classes.

Comment: oh ok ill look into that. The movement and rotation always change depending on user interaction. I must admit that im only starting with this kind of stuff so i could have missed something.

Comment: If you can manage to setup all the rotations and transitions you need in a CSS stylesheet, then simply add classes to elements to turn them on, I can guarantee that will give you a performance increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should increase performance in most cases, according to [this research](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/). But you need to set both `translate` and `rotate` in one `transform` value, like this:

```
var stylePos = 'translate(' + newPos.x + 'px' + ',' + newPos.y + 'px' + ')';
var styleRot = ' rotate(' + (body.GetAngle() * 57.2957795) + 'deg) translateZ(0)';
img.style.WebkitTransform = stylePos + ' ' + styleRot;
img.style.MozTransform = stylePos + ' ' + styleRot;
img.style.OTransform = stylePos + ' ' + styleRot;
img.style.msTransform = stylePos + ' ' + styleRot;
img.style.transform = stylePos + ' ' + styleRot;
```

In the code you posted in the question, rotation just replaces and overrides translation.

Comment: Also, you can simplify CSS and calculations a bit: `var stylePos = 'translate3d(' + newPos.x + 'px' + ',' + newPos.y + 'px' + ',0)';
var styleRot = ' rotate(' + body.GetAngle() + 'rad)';`